# AngularJS pass parameters in directive template to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

In my app i have such directives:

```
.directive('nodeList', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        scope: {
            nodes: '=ngModel',
            deleteArticle: '&',
            editArticle: '&'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray($scope.nodes)) {
                $element.append('<accordion close-others="true"><node ng-repeat="item in nodes" ng-model="item" delete-article="deleteArticle(node_item)" edit-article="editArticle(node_item)"></node></accordion>');
            } 
            $compile($element.contents())($scope.$new());
        }
    };
})

.directive('node', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        scope: {
            node: '=ngModel',
            deleteArticle: '&',
            editArticle: '&'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray($scope.node.Options) && $scope.node.Options.length > 0) {
                $element.append('<accordion-group><accordion-heading>{{node.Title}}   <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" ng-click=\"editArticle({node_item: node})\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#new-article\" class=\"action\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></i></a></accordion-heading><node-list ng-model="node.Options"></node-list>{{node.Content}}</accordion-group>');
            } else {
                $element.append('<accordion-group><accordion-heading>{{node.Title}}   <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" ng-click=\"editArticle({node_item: node})\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#new-article\" class=\"action\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></i></a></accordion-heading>{{node.Content}}</accordion-group>');
            }
            $compile($element.contents())($scope.$new());
        }
    };
})
```

and such html:

```
<node-list ng-model="articles" delete-article="deleteArticle(node_item)" edit-article="editArticle(node_item)"></node-list>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.editArticle = function(vArticle) {}
```

when i have only one directive - all is clear, but how to pass parameters when my directive is calling another directive? is it real? and how?

Comment: It will be easier to help you (and to get the bounty) if you will create a jsfiddle or plnkr for us, please

Comment: @Cherniv hm, i didn' know how to add ui bootstrap... http://embed.plnkr.co/LlzPgsWrwcYd59sa2wxd/preview

Comment: while compiling DOM, why do you need $scope.$new() inside isolated scope?

Comment: @pankajparkar to render childs of childs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change a very small piece of you code in order for your function call to receive the argument correctly

in your **nodeList** directive, call to your **node** like this:

```
<node ng-repeat="item in nodes" ng-model="item" delete-article="deleteArticle({node_item: node_item})" edit-article="editArticle({node_item: node_item})"></node>
```

and in your **node** directive, call to your **nodeList** like this:

```
<node-list ng-model="node.Options" delete-article="deleteArticle({node_item: node_item})" edit-article="editArticle({node_item: node_item})"></node-list>
```

So the reference "node_item" being passed correctly amongst children of children of children... to the top most parent (your controller:)

Have a look at this: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j1W9ht?p=preview)

The reason:

Your **<node-list>** has its own scope, you need to pass "node_item" to the parent scope (your controller), simple! The tricky part is that the function is being called inside a grandchild scope (the **<node>**), so you then again need to pass "node_item" from the grandchild to the child.

You also **don't** need to create a new scope when calling compile. The $scope object you have there was also a **new** scope from the parent scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate between directives by using a controller and by making this dependency explicit. A simple example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('foo', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function ($scope) {
        this.property = 'something';
      },
      link: function (scope, element) {
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('bar', function() {
    return {
      require: '^foo',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
          console.log(fooCtrl.property);
        scope.value = fooCtrl.property;
      }
    }
  })
```

Here, directive `bar` declares a dependency to directive `foo` as an enclosing directive. Therefore, the directives can communicate as the link function is passed an additional argument. This HTML snipped will therefore display `something`:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <foo><bar>{{ value }}</bar></foo>
</div>
```

You can [play with this example in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvoxqd4a/).

Comment: take a look at my example, i didn't know how to implement it there

Comment: i need to pass data from note which is currently clicked to controller wthis is not in directive

Answer (score 0):

**NodeList Directive**

Expose a controller API from your nodeList directive that your child node directives can call to delete or edit an article.

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    this.deleteArticle = function (node) {
        var index = $scope.nodes.indexOf(node);
        if (index >= 0) {
            $scope.nodes.splice(index, 1);
            $scope.$emit('articleDeleted', node);
        }

    }
    this.editArticle = function (node) {
        var index = $scope.nodes.indexOf(node);
        if (index >= 0) {
            $scope.$emit('articleEdited', node);
        }

    }
}
```

**Node Directive**

In your node directive, manually compile the nodeList directive to avoid recursion, and add links to call the nodeList controller's API:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, nodeListController) {
    var template = angular.element('<node-list ng-model="node.nodes" ng-hide="node.hidden"></node-list>');
     $element.append(template);
     $compile(template)($scope);

      $scope.delete = function (node) {
          nodeListController.deleteArticle(node);
      }

      $scope.edit = function (node) {
          nodeListController.editArticle(node);
      }
}
```

**Parent Controller:**

Use `$emit` to notify users of your directive that a node was edited or deleted.

```
$scope.$on('articleEdited', function (evt, node) {
    alert('Edited ' + node.Title);
});
$scope.$on('articleDeleted', function (evt, node) {
    alert('Deleted ' + node.Title);
});
```

```js
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
   var ctrl = app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.nodes = [{
       Title: 'Title 1',
       nodes: [{
         Title: 'Title 1.1',
         nodes: []
       }, {
         Title: 'Title 1.2',
         nodes: []
       }]
     }, {
       Title: 'Title 2',
       nodes: [{
         Title: 'Title 2.1',
         nodes: [{
           Title: 'Title 2.1.1',
           nodes: []
         }, {
           Title: 'Title 2.1.2',
           nodes: []
         }]
       }, {
         Title: 'Title 2.2',
         nodes: [{
           Title: 'Title 2.2.1',
           nodes: []
         }, {
           Title: 'Title 2.2.2',
           nodes: []
         }, {
           Title: 'Title 2.2.3',
           nodes: []
         }, {
           Title: 'Title 2.2.4',
           nodes: []
         }]
       }]
     }];
     $scope.$on('articleEdited', function(evt, node) {
       alert('Edited ' + node.Title);
     });
     $scope.$on('articleDeleted', function(evt, node) {
       alert('Deleted ' + node.Title);
     });


   });
   app.directive('nodeList', function($parse) {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
         nodes: '=ngModel'
       },
       template: '<div close-others="true"><node ng-repeat="item in nodes" ng-model="item" ></node></div>',
       controller: function($scope) {
         this.deleteArticle = function(node) {
           var index = $scope.nodes.indexOf(node);
           if (index >= 0) {
             $scope.nodes.splice(index, 1);
             $scope.$emit('articleDeleted', node);
           }

         }
         this.editArticle = function(node) {

           var index = $scope.nodes.indexOf(node);
           if (index >= 0) {
             $scope.$emit('articleEdited', node);
           }

         }
       },
       link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {}
     };
   });

   app.directive('node', function($compile) {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       require: '^nodeList',
       scope: {
         node: '=ngModel'
       },
       controller: function($scope) {

       },
       template: '<div><span ng-click="node.hidden = !node.hidden">{{node.Title}}</span><a href="#" ng-click="edit(node)">Edit</a> <a href="#" ng-click="delete(node)">Delete</a></div>',
       link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, nodeListController) {
         var template = angular.element('<node-list ng-model="node.nodes" ng-hide="node.hidden"></node-list>');
         $element.append(template);
         $compile(template)($scope);

         $scope.delete = function(node) {
           nodeListController.deleteArticle(node);
         }

         $scope.edit = function(node) {
           nodeListController.editArticle(node);
         }
       }
     };
   });
```

```css
  div {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <node-list ng-model="nodes">
  </node-list>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a service to pass any parameter that you use
You would need to add a trigger to get information when the directive is created 
this trigger should get the information from the service and use it
If it is created and get an undefined parameter it would be the first directive

I don't have a working codebut this concept would work.